# Проблема с загрузкой видео - AWS S3

Tags: fileupload, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Не могу загрузить в S3 видеофайл mp4 850 Мбайт. Выдаёт ошибку. Попробовал удалить бакет и снова создать. Теперь и бакет не могу создать.

> A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again.

Что можно сделать?

Comment: А о чём конкретно идёт речь? Здесь нет такой метки?

Comment: Как ещё конкретизировать свой вопрос?

Comment: Что такое S3? Какими средствами вы пользуетесь?

Comment: Прошу прощения, AWS. S3 - Сервис для хранения файлов.